# Free shaping in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles

I want to draw these two figure in tikz

[image]

Is it possible to draw these free shapes in tikz including characters and the dots? My ultimate goal is to make a lot of them and bring one big image but if I can understand how to do the smallest pieces, then I can make the rest by myself.

Thanks

Comment: You need to show what you have tried and describe what is causing you problems. This site is not about "do it for me" type of questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the shape with two extremely thick intersecting lines and a bunch of nodes. I picked 8mm for the line thickness but you can change `\mywidth`. Inside a tikzpicture you can use the macro `\crossfig[<tikz options>]{<coordinates>}{<label>}`. The `<tikz options>` would typically be color, but could include other things. The `<coordinates>` can be rectangular or polar (see code below).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
    mycirc/.style={circle, draw=black, thick, outer sep=0, anchor=#1, inner sep=0, minimum size=1.5ex},
    mytext/.style={text=black, anchor=#1, inner sep=0, outer sep=1pt}
}

\newcommand{\mywidth}{8mm}
\newcommand{\crossfig}[3][]{{
    \draw[line width=\mywidth, #1]($(#2)+(-\mywidth,0)$)node[mytext=west]{#3}node[mycirc=east]{}--($(#2)+(\mywidth,0)$)node[mytext=east]{#3}node[mycirc=west]{};
    \draw[line width=\mywidth, #1]($(#2)+(0,-\mywidth)$)node[mytext=south]{#3}node[mycirc=north]{}--node[mycirc=center, fill=black]{}($(#2)+(0,\mywidth)$)node[mytext=north]{#3}node[mycirc=south]{};
    }}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\crossfig[blue!50]{0,0}{Z}
\crossfig[red]{3,0}{X}
\crossfig[orange!50]{45:3}{M}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are amazing !!!!!